# Save different format file using one file uploader (MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on importing and saving different files from view page in MVC. As of now, I am able to upload different format and save in database. There are 3 controllers action to import text file, excel file and csv file.

I want to have only one file uploader. Based on the file which we upload, it needs to call that particular function and save the data. How can I achieve this? Will it be a good idea if I keep 3 radio buttons for 3 different formats to save/call that particular action method?

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
        switch(extension.ToLower())
        {
            case "xls":
                return RedirectToAction("ImportFromExcel", "Contact", new { data = file });

            case "txt":
                return RedirectToAction("ImportText", "Contact", new { data = file });
            case "csv":
                return RedirectToAction("ImportToCSV", "Contact", new { data = file });

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this. From your `HttpPostedFileBase` object, you can get to know the exact file extension of posted file. Like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);    
}
```

And then, accordingly, you can *Redirect* to particular action, or call respective save method.

```
switch (extension.toLower())
{
  case "xls":
      return RedirectToAction("SaveXlsData", "SomeController", new { data = file });
 //or call SaveXlsData(); from here
}
```

I hope this gives you idea.

Comment: I am having 3 controller actions. How can i call particular one action method based on the file I upload in view page?

Comment: @user7090664 see my updated answer. It gives you idea about that. If you still face issue, let me know.

Comment: Yeah I got the idea.. I wonder what if i use radio buttons in a view page and based on the file which i select it will redirect to that controller... ? Will it work?

Comment: Right now, I have 3 file uploader in a view page and 3 controllers action methods. But, I want one file upload to upload and 3 action methods to save the data,, What are the best ways to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean, if user selects *xls* radio button, then *Controler1/UploadXls* method will be called. and if it selects *docx* radio button, then *Controller2/UploadDocx* will be called? If this is true, then why do you need to have single upload method? I don't see this to be reasonable. Raher, keep a single upload method like above, regardless of the context it is called from. then perform required action.

Comment: You are right. I was just thinking about that solution.. The above mentioned solution is looks perfect for my scenario. I will add it now. Will let you know If i face prob. Thanks :)

Comment: Remove the other two uploaders from view. Only show one upload control. and decide inside Upload action, which save method to be called. This seems better.

Comment: Can you check this error? System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' Kindly check updated question. Getting error near extension